# Imageview and gridview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

[image]I'm trying to develop an Android application, I need a particular layout.

I want realize an activity composed by a imageview at the top of the screen and bottom a gridview.

The layout is static, can't change.

How i can realize it ?

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="info.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ovada"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="300dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Actually this code don't work as i want.

**** EDIT 1 ****

Ok, i have one problem:

1)What that i what obtain is:

- Image "logo" at the top of the screen
- Image "logo" above the Gridview
- Image and logo scrollable

when I scroll down the "page" I want scroll ALL the content of my page not only the grid view...

Answer (score 0):

add this to  your LinearLayout :

```
android:id="@+id/linear_id"
android:alignParentTop="true"
```

And GridView

```
android:layout_below="@id/linear_id
```

I also suggest that you get rid of the linear layout,because i don't see any use in adding it.

Answer (score 0):

For ListView and also for GridView, it is usually not a good idea to set the layout_height to wrap_content. "wrap_content" means make me as big as my children. This is hard to figure out for a listView and for GridView. It maybe better to set the height to match_parent.